# Flutter: Overlap Edge of Widget with second Widget

Tags: flutter

I want to overlap the bottom edge of a widget with another widget so that it looks like this:

[image: expected result]

I am using a stack to position the arrow button over the card. At the moment I just set the position with an invisible box above it. The issue is that this method only works for that exact resolution - it should be screen size independent.

The necessary code for the widget:

```
Stack(
 children: <Widget>[
  Container( //background
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
  ),
  FloatingActionButton(
   child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
   onPressed: () {},
  )
 ],
)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update - April 2021**

You can no longer use the `overflow` property in a `Stack` widget as it has been deprecated. Use `clipBehaviour` instead. Source: [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack/overflow.html)

You can use the `Stack` and `Positioned` widget to achieve this UI.

```
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      height: 150,
      width: 150,
    ),
    Positioned(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          print('FAB tapped!');
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      right: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: -26,
    ),
  ],
),
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Update - March 2022**

> The Area which is outside of `Stack` won't be clickable due to the platform limitation, and that is how the `Stack` widget works.
>
> You can learn more about the same in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19445).

Comment: Oh it was really simple. I did not know it also accepts negative values!

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana what if I don't want to set fix height and width ? it should wrap content then ?

Comment: the overflowed part of the fab is not clickable, what is the solution

Comment: If you can share some code snippet or ask a new question then it will be really helpful.

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana thanks it's posted here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62258640/10097848

Comment: Bad solution, the overflowed part is not clickable

Comment: Please look through this issue and check if any solution provided there works for you.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19445

Answer (score 1):

As of **November 2019** I'd like to add a second solution:

Using package: https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets

```
var widget1 = ...;
var widget2 = ...;

ColumnSuper(  
  children: [widget1, widget2],    
  innerDistance: -26,
  );
```

The difference from this solution to the one using `Stack` is that `Positioned` widgets in a `Stack` don't occupy vertical space. However, the `ColumnSuper` will have the size of all of its children widgets. *Note I am the author of this package.*

Comment: i prefer this one if this indeed works because position is not a good solution in a stack. if your bottom is too out of position, it cant be clickable anymore. but i dont know how to use ColumnSuper.

Comment: @chitgoks To use ColumnSuper you have to add the assorted_layout_widgets package to your pubspec.yaml configuration file. See here: https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets#-installing-tab-

Comment: yes i did. must have used it incorrectly. i will check it out again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try my package ([signed_spacing_flex](https://pub.dev/packages/signed_spacing_flex)). It's exactly the same as a normal `Column` (or `Row` and `Flex`). But it lets you set negative spacing which causes its children to overlap. You can also set which children should be on top when they overlap.

In your case it would be something like:

```dart
SignedSpacingColumn(
  spacing: -16.0,
  stackingOrder: StackingOrder.lastOnTop,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    FloatingActionButton(
      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      onPressed: () {},
    )
  ],
)
```

It works with expanded children if you need.