# Flutter overflowed positioned Button is not clickable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stack widget parenting a Positioned widget like this:

```
Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                print('FAB tapped!');
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: -26,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

That part of the fab which is placed outside the container is not clickable, what is the solution?
and here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19445 Go through this to check the work arounds

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this :

```
      Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>
            [
              Container(width: 150, height: 150, color: Colors.yellow),
              Container(width: 150, height: 28, color: Colors.transparent),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                print('FAB tapped!');
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
          ),
        ],
      )
```

you should keep button inside of stack if you want it to stay clickable

Comment: Superb solution bro

Comment: overflow deprecated! `clipBehavior: Clip.none` is proper way now

Answer (score 9):

The problem is when a child overflows on Stack that has `Clip.none` behavior, the part that is outside of Stack would not be recognized to be clicked.

**Solution :**

Wrap the `Stack` with `Column` and add the space you want to be outside of `Stack` :

```
final _clipSpace = 30;
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        DecoratedBox(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(// decorate the box //
           ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // column's children
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
         // clip space
        const SizedBox(height: _clipSpace,)
      ],
    ),
    const Positioned(
      child: _ActionButton(),
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: The best solution here, as it actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Providing an updated answer since `overflow` specification is deprecated after `v1.22.0-12.0.pre`. `clipBehavior` is the replacing property:

```
  Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    children: [
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>
        [
          Container(width: 150, height: 150, color: Colors.yellow),
          Container(width: 150, height: 28, color: Colors.transparent),
        ],
      ),
      Positioned(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            print('FAB tapped!');
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      ),
    ],
  )
```

*Note: credits to [@Amir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62258817/5585371)*

Answer (score 4):

up until now, there is now solution from Flutter, I should make a simple trick to solve this issue, I need to make a layout like this

[image]

the workaround is by adding a `SizedBox` below your background widget, the height of the `SizedBox` should be the same as the height of the overlaping widget.

like this

```
           Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                Column( // wrap the background in a column
                  children: [
                    const _HeaderBackground(),
                    SizedBox(height: 100), // add the SizedBox with height = 100.0
                  ],
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 16,
                  left: 4,
                  right: 4,
                  child: _ReferralCodeSection(customer), // the height  of this widget is 100
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the button in the last place of the Stack's children

```
Stack(children: [...., buttonWidget ])
```

Comment: Out of everything! This was the solution that worked for me! Silly Mistake ik!

Answer (score 2):

```
Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 180,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 150,
               child: Image.asset('assets/images/image.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover,)
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('FAB tapped!');
                },
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Fab button is not clickable because it renders outside of stack as you have given -ve bottom, Ideally, you should have parent container and inside it has all stack widget you should render it. 
Here I have used hardcoded values, but you should use media query as per your requirement

**Like:**

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.26,
               child: Image.asset('assets/images/jitesh.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover,)
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('FAB tapped!');
                },
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Flutter does not officially plan to solve this problem, so we can only use some hacking methods.

Here is my resolution with an example, you can use the following `OverflowWithHitTest` Widget directlly:

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// Creates a widget that can check its' overflow children's hitTest
///
/// [overflowKeys] is must, and there should be used on overflow widget's outermost widget those' sizes cover the overflow child, because it will [hitTest] its' children, but not [hitTest] its' parents. And i cannot found a way to check RenderBox's parent in flutter.
///
/// The [OverflowWithHitTest]'s size must contains the overflow widgets, so you can use it as outer as possible.
///
/// This will not reduce rendering performance, because it only overcheck the given widgets marked by [overflowKeys].
///
/// Demo:
///
/// class _MyPageStore extends State<MyPage> {
///
///   var overflowKeys = <GlobalKey>[GlobalKey()];
///
///   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
///     return Scaffold(
///       body: OverflowWithHitTest(
///
///         overflowKeys: overflowKeys,
///
///         child: Container(
///           height: 50,
///           child: UnconstrainedBox(
///             child: Container(
///               width: 200,
///               height: 50,
///               color: Colors.red,
///               child: OverflowBox(
///                 alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
///                 minWidth: 100,
///                 maxWidth: 200,
///                 minHeight: 100,
///                 maxHeight: 200,
///                 child: GestureDetector(
///                   key: overflowKeys[0],
///                   behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
///                   onTap: () {
///                     print('==== onTap;');
///                   },
///                   child: Container(
///                     color: Colors.blue,
///                     height: 200,
///                     child: Text('aaaa'),
///                   ),
///                 ),
///               ),
///             ),
///           ),
///         ),
///       ),
///     );
///   }
/// }
///
///
class OverflowWithHitTest extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const OverflowWithHitTest({
    required this.overflowKeys,
    Widget? child,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final List<GlobalKey> overflowKeys;

  @override
  _OverflowWithHitTestBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _OverflowWithHitTestBox(overflowKeys: overflowKeys);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _OverflowWithHitTestBox renderObject) {
    renderObject.overflowKeys = overflowKeys;
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(
        DiagnosticsProperty<List<GlobalKey>>('overflowKeys', overflowKeys));
  }
}

class _OverflowWithHitTestBox extends RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior {
  _OverflowWithHitTestBox({required List<GlobalKey> overflowKeys})
      : _overflowKeys = overflowKeys,
        super(behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent);

  /// Global keys of overflow children
  List<GlobalKey> get overflowKeys => _overflowKeys;
  List<GlobalKey> _overflowKeys;

  set overflowKeys(List<GlobalKey> value) {
    var changed = false;

    if (value.length != _overflowKeys.length) {
      changed = true;
    } else {
      for (var ind = 0; ind < value.length; ind++) {
        if (value[ind] != _overflowKeys[ind]) {
          changed = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!changed) {
      return;
    }
    _overflowKeys = value;
    markNeedsPaint();
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    if (hitTestOverflowChildren(result, position: position)) {
      result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
      return true;
    }
    bool hitTarget = false;
    if (size.contains(position)) {
      hitTarget =
          hitTestChildren(result, position: position) || hitTestSelf(position);
      if (hitTarget || behavior == HitTestBehavior.translucent)
        result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
    }
    return hitTarget;
  }

  bool hitTestOverflowChildren(BoxHitTestResult result,
      {required Offset position}) {
    if (overflowKeys.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var hitGlobalPosition = this.localToGlobal(position);
    for (var child in overflowKeys) {
      if (child.currentContext == null) {
        continue;
      }
      var renderObj = child.currentContext!.findRenderObject();
      if (renderObj == null || renderObj is! RenderBox) {
        continue;
      }

      var localPosition = renderObj.globalToLocal(hitGlobalPosition);
      if (renderObj.hitTest(result, position: localPosition)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```