# How to set a image inside a container but also expand outside the container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been grappling with a coding challenge for a while now, and despite my efforts, I can't seem to resolve it. Here's the problem:

I attempted to code a layout where everything is wrapped inside a Stack widget. The second child in the stack is an image, and I adjusted the container width accordingly. However, I'm facing an issue where the image isn't extending beyond the card, and the card padding seems fixed; I can't modify anything.

**here is the example design**

[image]

Here's the code snippet for reference:

```
children: [
        SizedBox(height: 37),
        const Text("Hey Mishal,",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 26,
              color: Color(0xFF0D1333),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            )),
        const Text("Find a course you want to learn",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Color(0xFF61688B),
              height: 2,
            )),
        Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 357,
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: kDeepBlueTheme, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Card(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 23),
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // SizedBox(height: 30, width: 100,),
                        const Text('50% off',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 27,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        const Text('For Any Courses',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                letterSpacing: 2,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 6,
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          //on pressed
                          onPressed: () async {},
                          //text to shoe in to the button
                          child: const Text('Join Now!',
                              style: TextStyle(color: kMainTheme)),
                          //style section code here
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                            )),
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 1,
                left: 100,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/person_home.png',
                  height: 230,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
```

and here is my result ,

[image]

No matter how I tweak the container width or adjust padding, the image won't go beyond the confines of the card. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Check if this can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091899/7652758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your Stack with a SizedBox and give it a height greater than the height of Card, use media query heights to make it responsive.

```
      SizedBox(
          height: 220,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const Text('50% off',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            const Text('For Any Courses',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    letterSpacing: 2,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 6,
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              //on pressed
                              onPressed: () async {},
                              //text to shoe in to the button
                              child: const Text('Join Now!',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                              //style section code here
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0),
                                shape:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                )),
                                backgroundColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://i.ibb.co/7Kr3Vc2/Screenshot-2022-02-23-at-6-11-05-PM-removebg-preview.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 210,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Result Will be like in pic..**
[image]

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 400,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,right: 5),
                child: Text('hello'),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 700,
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/place_holder_avatar.png',fit: BoxFit.cover,),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
```